# iOS - How to add display a string on a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

How can I show a string on a UIImage View?

Ok Ive got this currently:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  playerPositions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:box1,box2,box3,box4,nil];
  [box3 drawRect:box3.frame];
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
  [super drawRect:rect];

  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  CGContextSetFontSize(context, 11.5);

  CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 10.5, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
  CGContextShowText(context, "Tys", 5);
  CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 50, 60, "value", 5);
}
```

But no text shows when I test it.

Comment: I'm not sure where the problem is - the code, that I posted works well for me. Also, make sure, that the last param in CGContextShowText and CGContextShowText is an strlen of the text you are about to draw.

Comment: BTW, direct drawRect invocation in viewDidLoad is completely wrong. If you want to repaint component, you should invoke [box3 setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: You may also try to check usage examples here: http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch?hl=en&sa=N&q=CGContextShowTextAtPoint++lang:objectivec&ct=rr&cs_r=lang:objectivec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd override UIImageView's drawRect: method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFontSize(context, 11.5)

    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 10.5, kCGEncodingMacRoman)
    CGContextShowText(context, "value", 5)
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 50, 60, "value", 5)
}
```

**Updated:**

Yesterday I faced with the same problem. Ended up with `[NSString drawAtPoint:withFont]` method - it works perfectly.

Comment: I can't easily paste code in these comments, so Ive edited it into the question.  Now I have this code, how do I effectivly call it? Hasn't work for me yet, see above. Where am I going wrong?